# how can i spread images inside div using jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-plugins

i am looking for a jquery plugin that does the following:
let say i have a div container and 5 images that i want to display inside the div.
i want the images to be randomly located inside the div without overriding each other using the css position relative attribute.
for example:

```
<div class="floating_are" >
<img src="..." style="position:relative; top:5px; left:3px" />
<img src="..." style="position:relative; top:50px; left:30px" />
<img src="..." style="position:relative; top:80px; left:27px" />
<img src="..." style="position:relative; top:111px; left:92px" />
</div>
```

the output should be a div with 5 images randomly spread inside.
now, before i roll my sleeves and write it, i was wondering if any of you know of an existing plugin ?

Comment: Could you make a [jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/) of what you have so far? Because I'm pretty sure you meant to have `position: relative` on only the outer `div`, and `position: absolute` on the inner `div`s.

Comment: well, as far as code goes, i have nothing, i am just trying to avoid writing something that was already written. regarding the position of the outer div, it might be relative, it can also be fixed or anything else possible. cant force it to a certain positioning. regarding the inner div , what inner div ? you can just copy my code and paste it in the jsfiddle html section and see what i mean. only the html that you see the the result of my plugin, something like this:
$('div.floating_are').spread_img();
will randomly allocate positions to the inner images of div.floating_are

Comment: I'm merely talking about this: http://css-tricks.com/absolute-positioning-inside-relative-positioning/

Answer (score 0):

This might interest you [Scatter Gallery](http://codecanyon.net/item/drag-n-drop-scattered-gallery/235373)

Comment: This seems cool but i think the key words in the question are: "located inside the div without overriding each other". Collision/superposition is not the easiest thing to program :/